How to convert GET request To POST request when using fetch()
I am currently trying to convert my old, insecure, short GET requests to a more secure POST request. I am not sure how to do it.
function fetchData() {
        return fetch(`dataProcessing?action=submit&data=${encryptedFormValue}`)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error, 'warn');
            });
    }

I also have a backend for this that receives at dataProcessing.php
} else if ($_GET["action"] == "submit") {
    echo '{"response": "' . processData($_GET["data"]) . '"}';

Does anyone know how to convert this basic function into a POST request from a GET request?
I have tried using ChatGPT, searching on various webpages such as GET vs POST Request: The Difference, and could not find anything useful. What I am currently programming has to be secure since its a message encrypting website and GET requests are just not secure enough. I even tried looking at other stack overflow questions and all of them were so confusing.

POST isn't more modern than GET - as for updating your code ... use $_POST in php and use a body in the fetch with method set to POST - it's not hard

Or POST Request with Fetch API?

Who ever downvoted this question didn't had the chance to meet crazy development world with all constraints where we developers have to navigate.

Just move the parameters that should be hidden from the URL to the body.
function fetchData() {
  return fetch(`dataProcessing?action=submit`, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: `data=${encodeURIComponent(encryptedFormValue)}`
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error, 'warn');
    });
}

And use $_POST in the PHP code instead of $_GET (or use $_REQUEST so it works either way).

I got this error when using this javascript and the $_POST in the Backend. (Sorry error does not format Well.)
TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.
at fetchData (UpdateBody.js?=9.5.0:101:10)

at submit (UpdateBody.js?=9.5.0:110:5)

at handleSubmit (handle.js?=9.5.0:11:9)

at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):1:3327) 'warn'

Sources Listed Below:
https://zcrypt.kjzcorporation.com/Public/data/js/UpdateBody.js
https://zcrypt.kjzcorporation.com/Public/data/js/handle.js

Sorry, forgot the method: 'POST' option.

There's no syntax error. What error are you getting?

If the original code worked with GET, I don't see why this won't work the same with POST.

I found an error on .then((response) => response.json()), can you check this page because I am not sure what is wrong. https://zcrypt.kjzcorporation.com/ the error is in UpdateBody.js which the code is located.

The server is sending an empty response, not JSON. You can see this by looking at the request in the Network tab.

What can I do about that? It worked perfectly fine before I added the post request?

I have no idea. You probably messed something up when you changed $_GET to $_POST.

This is part of the source code for dataProcessing.php exept for functions.php which is the 2nd Layer.
} else if ($_GET["action"] == "isDebugMode") {
$configuration = json_decode(file_get_contents("./.config", true), true);
echo '{"response": "' . $configuration["DEBUG_MODE"] . '"}';
} else if ($_POST["action"] == "submit") {
echo '{"response": "' . processData($_GET["data"]) . '"}';
} else if ($_GET["action"] == "deleteOldRecords") {
deleteOldRecords();
echo '{"response": "Old records deleted successfully"}';
}

It uses $_POST instead of GET

$_GET["action"] should be $_POST["action"]

Those actions are for different elements of the code. I changed those to post even though it won't do anything, so there still is the error. I'll mark yours as an answer but i think mine is a special case. Please let me know if you figure out what's wrong.

You can keep action=submit in the URL if you want, then access it with $_GET. From your original question I thought you wanted to move everything into the post body. Or, like I said earlier, you can use $_REQUEST to allow parameters to be sent either way.

I simply wanted to convert all my GET requests to POST requests for longer messages and security. Is that what you mean?

What is the "security" you think you get from this? If it were a form submission, the advantage is that the parameters don't show up in the location bar. But this is not an issue for AJAX requests. The other difference is that the parameters don't show up in the server's access log.

If there are any passwords or other private information in the data, POST is good because you don't want those in the log.

Anyway, when you use POST, you can decide which parameters go in the post data, and which go in the URL.

The security is since it would not be using the URL bar for submissions. The main reason was to make the character limit infinite (basically infinite). There was no problems with the previous version I just wanted to increase the character limit and not use the URL bar, thats why I am using POST requests.

I've updated the answer to show how to put action in the URL and data in the post body.
